# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 45 and input n_features is 2

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, visualization, random-forest, valueerror

I'm trying to plot a Random Forest visualization for classification purposes with python 3.

Firstly, I read a CSV file where all necesary data is located. Here, Read_CSV() is a method who run correctly, giving three variables, **features** (vector with all feature names, specifically 45), **data** (only the data without label column. There are 148000 rows and 45 columns), **labels** (column of labels in integer format. There are 3 classes to classify as integers 0, 1 or 2. There are also 148000 rows in this vector).

```
    features,data,labels = Read_CSV()

    X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(data,labels,test_size=0.35,random_state=0)

    X = np.array(X).astype(np.float)
    y = np.array(y).astype(np.float)
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=30, cmap=cmap,
               clim=(y.min(), y.max()), zorder=3)
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')
    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    # fit the estimator
    model.fit(X, y)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*xlim, num=200),
                         np.linspace(*ylim, num=200))
    Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)
    # Create a color plot with the results
    n_classes = len(np.unique(y))
    contours = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.3,
                           levels=np.arange(n_classes + 1) - 0.5,
                           cmap=cmap, clim=(y.min(), y.max()),
                           zorder=1)
    ax.set(xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
```

This part of the code showed here is completely dedicated to obtain a plot like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt3a8.jpg)

When I run this code I obtain the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Carles/PycharmProjects/Article/main.py", line 441, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Carles/PycharmProjects/Article/main.py", line 388, in main
    visualize_classifier(RandomForestClassifier(),X_train, Y_train)
  File "C:/Users/Carles/PycharmProjects/Article/main.py", line 353, in visualize_classifier
    Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)
  File "C:\Users\Carles\PycharmProjects\Article\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 538, in predict
    proba = self.predict_proba(X)
  File "C:\Users\Carles\PycharmProjects\Article\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 578, in predict_proba
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X)
  File "C:\Users\Carles\PycharmProjects\Article\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 357, in _validate_X_predict
    return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, check_input=True)
  File "C:\Users\Carles\PycharmProjects\Article\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 384, in _validate_X_predict
    % (self.n_features_, n_features))
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 45 and input n_features is 2
```

Comment: Provide a minimal working example please. Your code can not run out of the box. And describe your question in more details.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this yourself? Please print `(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).shape`. According to the error, you are training and testing with a different number of features. Also, why are you doing a train/test split and then ignoring it?